# Writing tests with unknown variables

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to use PHPunit to do testing.

One of the tests I am writing requires scanning a directories sub directories for a certain folder.

I want to write a test that checks to make sure it does not fail if the folder does not exist.

The issue is that the directory it scans may or may not have the folder in it. so I am confused as to how I am meant to do this.

One option I could see is to move everything out of the directory, run the assertion, and then move everything back in, but that seems messy to me. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You may want to read up on [*mock objects*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of mock objects for code and data sources, but how would you use mock objects for directories and their contents?

Comment: Ideally, you would not have your class directly access the filesystem.  Instead, it would access a wrapper class.  For test purposes, you'd replace that wrapper class with a mock object, which emulates directories existing/not-existing in a controlled manner.

Comment: Specifically read up on http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem (mocking the filesystem using vfsStreamWrapper)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/bovigo/wiki/vfsStream

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you please Combine Oli's comment with yours and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpunit actually provides a means to mock the filesystem using [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream). This is described in the [PHPUnit documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem) (specifically look at example 10.19 to see how this is used). vfsStream acts as a wrapper for the filesystem.